# Golang's GORM not adding associations to "has many" relationship

Tags: go, go-gorm

I just started using [GORM](http://gorm.io) and tried to build a "has many relationship". I'm trying to add an association to Previous.Holdings (I think I followed the [docs](http://gorm.io/docs/associations.html) correctly) but when I try to do a `select * from previous` I don't see anything showing up in the database. Any idea on what I'm missing.

```
import (
    orm "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)    

type Previous struct {
    orm.Model

    Holdings []Holding `gorm:"foreignkey:ID"`
}

type Holding struct {
    ID uint `gorm:"primary_key"`

    Symbol string
    PurchaseDate time.Time
    SellDate time.Time
}

func main() {
    t1, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2017-06-16")
    h := Holding{
        Symbol: "abc",
        PurchaseDate: t1,
    }
    db.Model(&Previous{}).Association("Holdings").Append(h)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create your `previous` table. You can make that by making migrations. You probably should make that migrations after db connection initialization. e.g.

```
db.AutoMigrate(&Previous{})
```

---

So when u using `db.Model(&Previous{})` you not saving any entity and if u wanna make asscociation with `Holdings` entity you need as first step to `Save` or `Find` existing `Previous` record by doing e.g.

```
previous := &Previous{}
db.Save(previous)
```

After that you can append your holding record to `Model` like you do in your code but changing referenced `Previous`. So it will look like this

```
h := Holding{
    Symbol:       "abc",
    PurchaseDate: t1,
}
db.Model(previous).Association("Holdings").Append(h)
```

---

I don't know if its for testing but when you modeling entities you can make referenced id whithout specifing foreign key also you are using your `Holding` ID as ForeignKey so ID of `Previous` will be your ID of `Holding`.

For me your model declaration should look like this (`PreviousID` will be automaticaly signed as foreign key for Previous)

```
type Previous struct {
    orm.Model

    Holdings []Holding
}

type Holding struct {
    ID           uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    PreviousID   uint
    Symbol       string
    PurchaseDate time.Time
    SellDate     time.Time
}
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include that when I wrote this question but I do have it included in my code.